# Hacer un strlwr en mips

Tags: ensamblador, mips32

Necesito pasar una cadena que esta en mayúsculas a minúsculas pero no se que puedo gastar en mips, se que en C se gasta el strlwr pero no conozco el código en ensamblador, alguien me puede ayudar, he buscado información pero no me aparece nada, tengo que utilizar el código ascii?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir leyendo cada carácter y comparándolo si es mayor a 96, si es así, le restas directamente al carácter 32, ya que MIPS maneja a las letras como bytes y es posible hacer lo anterior, debes ir almacenando o en su defecto imprimiendolo